# errors thrown from here are not handled because the enclosing catch is not exhaustive in context.save

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, try-catch, xcode8

I am with a problem do and try after of the update  of the xcode to version 8.3.2. The code was working, but after of that update does not anymore. It conform the code below:

```
func saveContext() -> NSError?{// It saving
        do {
            if  context == context {
                try context.save()
           // taskNameTextField.text=nil
            }
        } catch let error as! NSError? {
            print("error saving core data: \(error)")
            return error
        }
        return nil
    } //
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Should just be `catch let error as NSError` without the random unnecessary punctuation.

Comment: @dan the problem is that error isn't an NSError in Swift 3. It's an Error.

Comment: @DanielT. you can bridge `Error` to `NSError`

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out that the Apple converter doesn't catch all the problems in the code when updating from Swift 2 to Swift 3. You need to update some stuff yourself. One of the things it doesn't catch are all the references to NSError. It misses several places where NSError needs to be converted to Error.

```
func saveContext() -> Error?{ // remove the `NS` from Error here.
    do {
        if  context == context { // this is always true, remove it.
            try context.save()
        }
    } catch { // remove the `let error as! NSError?` from here
        print("error saving core data: \(error)")
        return error
    }
    return nil
}
```

The simpler version of this function is:

```
func saveContext() -> Error? {
    do {
        try context.save()
        return nil
    } catch {
        return error
    }
}
```

or implement the `catch` one level up and it becomes:

```
func saveContext() throws {
    try context.save()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Handling Errors Using Do-Catch**
You use a do-catch statement to handle errors by running a block of code. If an error is thrown by the code in the do clause, it is matched against the catch clauses to determine which one of them can handle the error.

Here is the general form of a do-catch statement:

```
do {
    try expression
   // statements
} catch pattern 1 {
   // statements
} catch pattern 2 where condition {
   //statements
} catch {
  // statements
}
```

You must have to write last default "catch" Blok same like "Switch_case" default:

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution in swift 4.2

```
 func saveContext() -> NSError? {
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print("error saving core data: \(error) \(error.description)")
      return error
    }
    return nil
  }
```